# Transition opacity between 3 images using slide

Tags: jquery, css, transition, opacity, jquery-ui-slider

I have three images stacked one on top of the other with a jQuery slide beneath them. I want the image opacity to change so that as you slide from left to right the images will fade in/out smoothly in order like so:

Slide at far left. 
img 1 at 100% opacity
img 2 at 0
img 3 at 0

Slide in the middle.
img 1 at 0
img 2 at 100
img 3 at 0

Slide at far right
img 1 at 0
img 2 at 0
img 3 at 100%

I have a Fiddle setup at http://jsfiddle.net/greggbanse/PWc6m/ I know the code is wrong but I could use a few pointers on how best to execute this. TIA.

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider({

        range: "min",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,

            slide: function (event, ui) {
                var r = (ui.value); 
                $("#img1,#txt1").css({'opacity':r/100});
                $("#img2,#txt2").css({'opacity':1-(r/100)});
                $("#img3,#txt3").css({'opacity':2-(r/100)});
            }   
        })
    });
```

HTML

```
<img id="img1" src="http://www.norwich.edu/wp-content/uploads/home_oral_history.jpg" style="position:absolute;left:0;z-index:3000;">
<div id="txt1" style="position:absolute;left:0;z-index:3000;top:160px;background-color:#fff;">This is the text for the first image.</div>
<img id="img2" src="http://www.norwich.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/condoleezza-rice.jpg" style="position:absolute;left:0;z-index:2000;">
<div id="txt2" style="position:absolute;left:0;z-index:2000;top:160px;background-color:#fff;">More text but this is the explanation text for the second image.</div>
<img id="img3" src="http://www.norwich.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/CGCSresidency.jpg" style="position:absolute;left:0;z-index:1000;">
<div id="txt3" style="position:absolute;left:0;z-index:1000;top:160px;background-color:#fff;">And now we have yet more text for the third and final image.</div>
<div id="slider" style="height:10px; width:400px; position:relative;top:240px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked a little your formulas:

```
$("#img1,#txt1").css({'opacity':1-(r*0.02)});
$("#img2,#txt2").css({'opacity':r*0.02+Math.floor((1-r*0.02))*(r-50)*0.04});
$("#img3,#txt3").css({'opacity':(r*0.02)-1});
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PWc6m/2/).

By my understanding, this is what you tried to achieve, but does it serve your case?